# What name will show ps after exec*()?

Tags: c, linux, unix

If in `myProgram` I call

```
execv("otherProgram", argv);
```

What will name will `ps` show? `myProgram`, `otherProgram` or value of `argv[0]`? And is name showed by `ps` same to the name matched by `killall`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends what you ask ps for.
On Linux, using Debian's ps:

'ps -o comm' will show the basename of the filename passed to execve() - which may or may not match argv[0].  'ps -o args' will show you the whole command line (which might have an interpreter stuck on the front).  This will include argv[0] but is not limited to that.

'ps' on its own defaults to the former; 'ps -f' and 'ps -l' to the latter.

Comment: And what name will `killall` match?

Comment: Debian's killall has several dozen lines of code to figure out a name to match against in various different ways.  You're best off looking at it directly (or rather, at your distribution's killall).

Answer (score 0):

> What will name will ps show

Why don't you just try it?

It should show `argv[0]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be same on every system. I tried to google and could not find clear answer, so I thought it's a good place to put a definite answer if someone knows it.

Comment: According to http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC22 `argv[0]` is used on BSDish systems.